# Apostrophe at beginning/end of search string not treated as part of a word by RegEx

Tags: mysql, regex, apostrophe

We run a dictionary and have run into a problem with searches that contain an apostrophe at the start of a search string. In English words like *'twas* are quite rare but in the language we're dealing with, ' is considered a word character and extremely common at the start of a phrase (for instance *'s*) and also at the end of words (for instance *a'*).

Oddly enough, RegEx searches don't seem to struggle with this if it's in the middle (for example *air a' bhòrd* gets all the desired results) but ' at beginning or end of a search string is not treated as part of a word by RegEx.

We've ascertained this is part of the RegEx specification (only alphanumeric characters and _ are treated as part of a word) but we're wondering if it is it possible to write a RegEx expression that also treats apostrophes as part of a word?

This is what we're currently getting:

```
-- Demonstration on MySQL 5.6.21 Community
Select ('cat''s' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', 'cat''s', '[[:>:]]'));
-- returns 1
Select ('''cat''s' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' ,'''cat''s' ,'[[:>:]]' ));
-- returns 0
Select ('_cat''s' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' ,'_cat''s' ,'[[:>:]]' ));
-- returns 1
Select ('-cat''s' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' ,'-cat''s' ,'[[:>:]]' ));
-- returns 0
Select (' cat''s' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' ,' cat''s' ,'[[:>:]]' ));
-- returns 0
Select ('cat''' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]' ,'cat''' ,'[[:>:]]' ));
-- returns 0
```

Any suggestions greatly welcomed :)

Comment: Are you testing the entire column for being a "word"?  Or are you checking for a "word" inside a longer string?

Comment: Is a quoted `'cats'` a "word"?  In your test case, it would be `'''cats'''`.  Ditto for `"cats"`.

Comment: If GMB's Answer turns out to be inadequate, please provide a longer list of "words" that should pass and a list of "words" that don't pass.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should provide your own definition of what a word character is, instead of relying on default ICE word boundaries (`[[:<:]]`, `[[:>:]]`). From [the mysql 5.6  documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) :

> A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (`_`).

That would mean : `'^|[^[:alnum:]_]'`

```
^             -- the beginning of the string
|             -- OR
[^            -- any character OTHER than
    [:alnum:]     -- an alphanumeric character
    _             -- an underscore
]
```

And ICE end of string would be : `'[^[:alnum:]_]|$'`, where `$` represents the end of string.

You could just modify this to add the single quote in the character class, like :

- beginning : `'^|[^[:alnum:]_'']'`
- end : `'[^[:alnum:]_'']|$'`

Here is your regex :

```
SELECT (val REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', 'cat''s', '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)'));
```

[See the demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3yAebJmVYpoZVzX2jJFNns/2)

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

---

**Query #1**

```
Select ('cat''s'
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', 'cat''s', '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)')) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
Select ('''cat''s' 
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', '''cat''s', '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)' )) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

**Query #3**

```
Select ('_cat''s'
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', '_cat''s' , '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)' )) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

**Query #4**

```
Select ('-cat''s'  
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', '-cat''s' , '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)' )) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

**Query #5**

```
Select (' cat''s' 
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', ' cat''s' , '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)' )) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

**Query #6**

```
Select ('cat'''
    REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^[:alnum:]_''])', 'cat''' , '([^[:alnum:]_'']|$)' )) res;
```

```
| res |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---